# Center page content in songs package

Tags: songs

I want to use the `songs` package to create a single lyrics sheet. All the enumeration stuff hence is not really interesting, and I would like to have the lyrics centered on the page rather then aligned on the left hand side. I tried fiddling around with the size of the left margin, but I wasn't able to do that with variables such as `\linewidth`. Is there an easy way to center a whole `\begin{songs} ... \end{songs}` environment?

Comment: Could you please give a complete [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) so we have something to play with. Without testing: does `\centering` help?

Answer (score 1):

The songs package's `slides` mode does this.  Just load the package in the following way:

```
\usepackage[slides]{songs}
```

Slides mode omits chords by default, but you can include them with:

```
\usepackage[slides,chorded]{songs}
```